# mysql - storing json, double quote escape issue

Tags: mysql, json, vbscript

I've been chasing a JSON bug about and discovered that I'm getting different results if I load a file from disk as to loading the (apparently) same file from the db.

Mysql seems to be stealing my escape characters. (I'm using vbscript; my connect string is `Driver={MySQL ODBC 5.1 Driver};Server=localhost;Database=foo;User=foo;Password=f00;Option=3;`)

On doing a conn.execute(...)

```
update courses set config = '{"set": "value in \"here\" ok?"}' where id = 21;
select config from courses where id = 21;
// prints changed value {"set": "value in "here" ok?"}
```

What's going on here? Why is mysql taking out my `\"` and turning them into `"`?

If I use workbench on the server (windows 2003) and use the feature "load value from file" in the results pane, I can import the json to the field and it retains the proper escape sequence values. But doing an update / insert, the escape sequence characters are ***lost***.

Answer (score 0):

MySQL does escaping as well. If you need escape characters back when retrieving data, you'll need to escape the escape characters. E.g. "\\".

Comment: argh. so I can't just store an exact value in a text field and get the same value back out again, without jumping through hoops? I should have stuck with sqlite. is there a pragma setting to disable this? there's a setting - http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/sql-mode.html#sqlmode_no_backslash_escapes - would I have to execute this before every single query? This would suck balls.

Answer (score 0):

The issue will solve when you use `\\"`.
But why you have to add an extra `\` ??
`PHP` will treat `\"` as escape sequence and replace it with `"`and your final query will be like `'{"set": "value in "here" ok?"}'`.
By adding extra `\` you can build `'{"set": "value in \"here\" ok?"}'` (PHP will replace `\\` with `\`)